# openpyxl: How to get total of cells if there is a phrase in the description?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

completely new to python and openpyxl here, thanks for helping:
I have a spreadsheet that records my income and expenses, with dates, description, debit and credit amount.
I wanted to used openpyxl to automate the process of adding values that are in a particular category.

Sample data:
[My spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVZnh.png)

So lets say I want to know how much I have spent on giving out wages, I find the cells that contain "wages" then add up the total.

Here is the code I have written so far, and I didn't know how to select the cell and add up the total.

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook('sampledata.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 2)
    total = 0
    search_phrase = "Wage"
    if cell.value is None:
        continue
    else:
        if search_phrase in cell.value:
            total = float(cell.value) + total
            total_cell = sheet.cell(5, 5)
            total_cell.value = total

wb.save("sampledata2.xlsx")
```

Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change two things to make this work, assuming I've understood your question correctly:

1. First, you need to move `total = 0` before your `for` loop. As it is, the total is reset to 0 every time you go to a new row.
2. When increasing your total, you need to add the value from the "Debit" column, not the "Description." So instead of `total = float(cell.value) + total`, you want `total += float(cell.offset(column=2).value)`. (`+=` is shorthand for `total = total + ...`)

You can also take your two lines with `total_cell` out of the `for` loop (just unindent them) so they are only executed after the loop is completed.

One other thing: your search phrase is currently case sensitive. If you want to make it work for any combination of upper and lower case, use `if search_phrase.casefold() in str(cell.value).casefold()`.